# How to set scope(or role) of nuxt $auth.user?

Tags: vue.js, oauth-2.0, nuxt.js

I am using nuxt-auth with google oauth2 config, here is my   `nuxt.config.js` config:

```js
auth: {
  scopeKey: 'scope',
  strategies: {
    google: {
      client_id: process.env.GOOGLE_KEY,
      codeChallengeMethod: '',
      scope: ['profile', 'email'],
      responseType: 'token id_token'
    }
  },
  redirect: {
    login: '/login',
    logout: '/logout',
    home: '/',
    callback: '/welcome'
  }
},
router: {
  middleware: ['auth']
},
```

I use this code to login

```js
this.$auth.loginWith('google')
```

I want to setup a role for user (visit app database) after successful login, so I added this code to my **welcome.vue** (oauth2 callback page)

```html
<script>
export default {
  mounted () {
    const user = this.$auth.user
    user['scope'] = 'some_role_from_db'
    this.$auth.setUser(user)
  }
}
</script>
```

but this code is never called, because application is immediately redirected to the page that user has selected before visiting login page (**welcome.vue** html markup is shown for 1 sec).

What is the correct way to set some attributes to this.$auth.user immediately after login? Is there some easy way to set role to user after OAUTH2 authentication?

Comment: What causes redirection in your app ? Is it automatic or manual redirection to last page ? @BogdanTimofeev

Comment: @Batuhan it is automatic redirect to the page user has selected before logging in, I am using 'auth' middleware, edited the post

Comment: i.e I go to localhost:3000/apps page, it redirects me to localhost:3000/login, I log in with Google, it redirects me to localhost:3000/welcome and then immediately back again to localhost:3000/apps - but now this page is shown because I am authorized

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've added this section to my auth object in `nuxt.config.js`

```
rewriteRedirects: false
```

and so my app always redirects me to `home` url, and on home page I can access auth object like

```
<script>
export default {
  mounted () {
    const user = this.$auth.user
    user['scope'] = 'some_role_from_db'
    this.$auth.setUser(user)
  }
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

user roles must came from server and it wrong to define it from client side ,
but if that is importent you can do it like that :

```
this.$auth.loginWith('google').then(() => {
    const user = this.$auth.user
    user['scope'] = 'some_role_from_db'
    this.$auth.setUser(user)
})
```

Comment: I have tried this, but then() callback is never executed because page changes after I select my google account

Comment: 'some_role_from_db' should come from server, it is constant just for example

Comment: ok then get it with your user object

Comment: user object comes from Google, It has no information about roles in my particular application, roles should be stored in my app database

Comment: How do you set scope from server?